# How to catch exceptions within a class in PHP?

Tags: php, exception, try-catch, php-7

I have a class with many functions that is used to commit and select data from a MySql database.  In order to save time I need a`try-catch` block that catches all exceptions within the class.
I have tried my code below but it does not work because the `try` block gives a syntax error.

Code

```
class DB_FunctWeb {
    public $db;
//my try block starts
try {
    function __construct($conn) {
        $this->$db=$conn;
    }

    function __destruct() {

    }
    //....more functions....

} catch (Exception $e) {
    $errnumber = $db->errno;

    header("./creator.php");
    if ($errnumber === 1062) {
        insertInfo(" Duplicate entry please re-enter farm name.");
        // echo $e->getMessage();
    } else {
        insertInfo(" An error occurred. Items where not added.");
    }
} finally {
    closeconn($db);
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_OFF);
}
}
```

Question
How do you catch exceptions within a class?

Comment: Each function needs its own try/catch block

Comment: @Nick Is there no other way to add one ```try-catch``` block for all?  For e.g. include a file with ```try-catch``` and in between ```try-catch``` block call all functions OR I read something about a ```__call``` method that is also an option.

Comment: If you declared all your methods private, you could intercept the calls using `__call` and use that to wrap a try/catch around the function call. Something like `public function __call($name, $arguments) {
        try {
            $this->$name(...$arguments);
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "error!";
        }
    }` perhaps?

Comment: @Nick Thanks! That clarifies a few uncertainties.  First will have to understand a bit more before trying that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You catch the instantiated object of the class, and not the class definition:

```
try {
   $dbweb = new DB_FunctWeb($conn);
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
 ...
}
```

Comment: If within the class there is functions that inserts data into a datatable, will this catch exceptions of the function within the class e.g. ```try {$dbweb = new DB_FunctWeb($conn); $dbweb->commitFarmname($name, $conn);} catch (Exception $e) { ... }```

Comment: It will catch any exception thrown in the DB_FunctWeb constructor or the commitFarmname() method. You can wrap any *code* in a try block if you want to handle any exception thrown within that code. `But`  it's not possible to put the definition of class methods inside a try block.